# Drupal Subscription Webforms

Tags: webforms

I have Subscription webFrom which I need to use it with different products.

Subscription Webfrom will ask  Email and Name to be submitted.

When I click on the product it take to the subscription form where the user enters the name and the email. How do I know to which product the subscription form was submitted. How do I pass the product information to the subscription webform without user having to select the product again or avoid create a same subscription form to each product.

Thanks

B L Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem it can be done by passing information through url as said [here](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/webform-passing-info-through-url)